# inline svg in CSS (base64 vs urlencode issue)

Tags: css, svg

due to https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/

That base64 is 33% bigger than original, but raw svg is not worked on IE. So I need to urlencode it.

Here's the problem, when I urlencode it, the result is BIGGER than base64's result. (I use urlencode & rawurlencode function in PHP, both are bigger than base64_encode)

So why base64 svg is not recommended? Am I somewhere wrong or misunderstanding?

Comment: From a brief glance over the article, the author himself claims that "he's no expert". I wouldn't apply particular credence to his guidelines. In fact, I don't think he really understands how compression works in his claim that pure svg will *obviously* compress more than its base-64 encoded equivalent.

Comment: Are you comparing the size before or after gzipping?

Comment: without gzipping (comparing character length only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right

It is the best solution to `base64encode` inline SVG because of IE needs to `urlencode` it. But `urlencoded` is the same or even much bigger than base64 encode. Thats tricky!